# How can I dynamically add a **must** reviewer to Pull request on github via github API

Tags: github, github-api, circleci

**Background:**

In Github, we have a shared project which can be updated by all the teams. In this project we have a lot of files belong to one or multiple teams. We can identify a file belong to which team by checking the files(.py) header, like:

```
# protected-by: teamA, teamB
```

Now, I am working on protecting the file by adding the `teamA` and `teamB` as **must** reviewers when anyone send a PR having updates on the file.

**Problem**

So far, I can use CircleCI to detect the changed files, extract the protectors list and set them as reviewers by using Github API like this:

```
curl --location --request POST -u $GH_USER:$GH_TOKEN \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
          https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/PROJECT/pulls/${pr_number}/requested_reviewers \
          -d "{\"team_reviewers\":[$reviewers]}"
```

The problem is the reviewers I added are not **must** reviewers like **CODEOWNER**, users still could be able to merge without protectors' review. So I am thinking is there anyway to make `PR must be reviewed by some reviewers, otherwise can not be merged` by using Github API or other methods?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `CODEOWNERS` for this?  That's the tool that GitHub provides for this purpose.

Comment: Because we don't want to open the edit permission on `CODEOWNERS` to users, and if we (as admin) do that for users, there will be too much work for us.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is going to be that you can't add such a mandatory reviewer other than by using `CODEOWNERS`.